# OrbitControls issue when zoom in a larger webpage

Tags: javascript, scroll, three.js, controls, zooming

I embed misc_controls_orbit example in 800x600 frame inside a larger webpage with other content.

My problem is when i scroll my mousewheel, it's do both scroll the webpage and zoom my object even when my mouse is inside or outside the frame.

What i need now is when my mouse is inside the frame, it's only zoom the object, not scroll all webpage with it, and when the mouse is outside the frame, it's will only scroll the webpage, not zoom object (like Sketchfab embeds here:http://www.klaasnienhuis.nl/2012/09/sketchfab-embeds/ )

This problem seem like only happen with OrbitControls, Trackball is not, i had search and try in many way but still no result, can anyone help me? (sr my bad english, hope you understand, plz ask if you don't)

this is original misc_controls_orbit code i'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <title>three.js webgl - orbit controls</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            color: #000;
            font-family:Monospace;
            font-size:13px;
            text-align:center;
            font-weight: bold;

            background-color: #fff;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #info {
            color:#000;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;

        }

        a {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - orbit controls example
    </div>

    <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var container, stats;

        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

        var cross;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 500;

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );

            // world

            var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 10, 30, 4, 1 );
            var material =  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color:0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

            for ( var i = 0; i < 500; i ++ ) {

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.position.x = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 1000;
                mesh.position.y = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 1000;
                mesh.position.z = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 1000;
                mesh.updateMatrix();
                mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                scene.add( mesh );

            }


            // lights

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
            light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
            scene.add( light );


            // renderer

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
            renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            render();

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();

        }

        function render() {

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            stats.update();

        }


    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Try `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );` Be sure to define `renderer` first.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i tried but it's still scroll the whole webpage even mouse in or out the frame.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a canvas to render webgl and add an event listener

Use this html:

```
<canvas id="webglcanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

with this javascript

```
function onMouseWheel(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    /* TODO : your zoom */
}

function addMouseHandler(canvas) {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('onwheel' in document ? 'wheel' : 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false);
}

function createScene(canvas) {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: canvas,
        antialias: true
    });

    // Set the viewport size
    renderer.setSize(canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("webglcanvas");

    // create the scene
    createScene(canvas);

    // add mouse handling so we can rotate the scene
    addMouseHandler(canvas);

    // Run the run loop
    run();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i realize this problem only happen in the current OrbitControls, the old OrbitAndPanControls and the TrackballControls is not happen, should i report this like a bug?